# g:each in grails layout template

Tags: grails

I'm trying to generate my nav links from a backend query in my layout template. I see no way to for me to use g:each in the template and communicate with a controller. How would I go about doing this?

layouts/main.gsp

```
<g:layoutHead />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <ul>
         //How do you specify a controller, I would rather not have to pass these values in from every gsp view.
         <g:each  var="i" var="navLink" in="${navLinks}">
            <li>Title: ${navLink.linkTitle}</li>
          </g:each> 
        </ul>
    </header>
    <g:layoutBody />
</body>
```

Comment: You're going to have to give more details or examples of what you are trying to do (example code would be best) to get a good answer.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore, sorry I thought the question was pretty self explanatory. Please see edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given what you are trying to do here it's best to encapsulate this into a tag library that you can use in your GSPs and fetch data from a service. For example:

```
package com.example

class MyExampleTagLib {
  def myService
  static namespace = 'example'

  def renderMenu = { attrs, body ->
    List data = myService.fetchData()
    out << '<ul>'
    data.each {
      out << '<li>'
      out << it.linkTitle
      out << '</li>'
    }
    out << '</ul>'
  }
}
```

Then in your GSPs: `<example:renderMenu />`

Comment: I think our going to want to set the defaultEndcodeAs to raw, but other than that worked perfectly, thanks.